# new builds showing old pages on ionicframework

Tags: ionic-framework

I have created a ionic react app for cross-platform mobile apps , and using https://dashboard.ionicframework.com/ to generate builds

on home page, changed complete design and data.
now when I generate new build, for ios/android first it shows updated page and data
but when I refresh screen with pull to refresh it changes back to old design and data
and some time going to another screen and than coming back to home screen it shows old stuff

while the web version works fine

don't know whats happening here

Comment: There is no way to answer this question without code or reproducible example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You need to do ionic build first then npx cap sync.It sounds like you haven't build it yet.